# Can you guess the two famous titles?

Tags: knowledge, wordplay

I took two famous titles.

From each and every word in those titles I replaced a single letter with another letter to form new words.

Then I scrambled all the new words from both the titles to get:

> Go get any lime pie like Bo did

What are the two titles? What is the common theme?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two titles are:

> **No Time to Die**
>  (Go lime Bo did)
>
>  and
>
>  **Live and Let Die**
>  (like any get pie)

These are both:

> Films featuring the character **James Bond** where the title ends with the word 'Die'.

Comment: Very fast solve.

Comment: Okay Stiv how did you do that?

Comment: @VikR Picked on the smallest words first, which looked like they might be 'to', and reasoned that 'any' might be 'and'. Then pondered 'did', reasoning there weren't many words you could make by changing just one letter, and once I'd settled on which one I thought it was, I considered the other words, changing one letter at a time to consider some likely candidates. 'lime' gave me a connection with the 'did' word I'd found, which gave me one answer, and the second followed shortly afterwards since I knew there was a theme :)

Comment: Wow you are really good at this.